# How can I use numbers with angular.js without comma and dot?

Tags: angularjs, formatting, numbers

I m new at angular.js
I have a ID column in my grid so I dont want to use formatted numbers with comma or dot. Should I use replace method or related regex expression?
I used like:

```
{{value | number: 0}}
```

For example(10000 is 10,000 in my application I want to use like 10000)

Comment: Please post your code snippet. Anyone cant write your code from scratch.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Then don't use the number filter?

Else, if you want it to be a number type create a custom filter:

```
app.filter('customNumber', function() {
    return function(value) {
        return parseInt(value, 10) //convert to int
    }
})
```

template:

```
{{value | customNumber}}
```